# Cannot invoke methods on a COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com

I had a problem with a COM component in .NET. It would instantiate but threw exceptions every time I called a method on it.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  What is the exception you're getting?  How are you creating it?  *Show some of your code... it helps*

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code it's really difficult. I don't know that much about COM but you might want to check if your .net program is compiling for 32 or 64 bit and depending on your platform you may have to explicitly set the threading model on the entry point to your application, e.g. in a windows console application you'd do:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
```

I remember having a similar issue once upon a time but can't remember for sure if this fixed it or not. Some more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx

Comment: I set the attribute and switched to 32 bits and it worked. Thank you!